# What is that function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the set of the convergence in the reals of the series
$$f(x):= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 n \sin \left (n+\frac x n\right)?$$ Is the function $f(x)$ bounded?

Edit: more exact title.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any ideas?

Comment: The series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 n \sin \left (\frac x n\right) $$ converges for each $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: did you try to seperate it as $sin(n+\dfrac{x}{n})=sin(n)cos(\dfrac{x}{n})+cos(n)sin(\dfrac{x}{n})$ and ...?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Answer (score 1):

For any fixed $x$; and any $N\geq 1$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \sin \left (n+\frac x n\right) &= 
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \sin n \cos \frac{x}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} \cos n \sin \frac{x}{n}
\end{align*}
Now,

- $\frac{\sin n}{n} \cos \frac{x}{n} = \frac{\sin n}{n} - \frac{\sin n}{2n^3}x^2 + o(\frac{1}{n^3})$; the first series converges iff $\sum \frac{\sin n}{n}$ does. It does.
- $\lvert \frac{1}{n} \cos n \sin \frac{x}{n} \rvert \leq \frac{\lvert x\rvert}{n^2}$ (as $\vert \sin t\rvert \leq \lvert t\rvert$): the second series converges as well.

Comment: Is $ o(\frac{1}{n^3})$ independent of $x$?

Comment: Yes, as $x$ is fixed (the $o()$ is taken w.r.t $n$).

Comment: Why is this  true? Please base it.

Comment: For any *fixed* $x$, the sum will converge. This proves pointwise convergence of the series (not uniform convergence or any stronger form of convergence).

Comment: I see unfounded words, not a math proof. BTW, how about the boundess of $f(x)$?

Comment: The o() is taken wrt n, meaning any other quantity is fixed; is a constant. And the proof above, as it only shows the series converges pointwise, does not say anything about f's being bounded or not (and never claimed so).

(the o() means that the remaining terms of the expansion are negligible in front of $1/n^3$; i.e. that even multiplied by $n^3$, they go to $0$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$.)

Comment: Vote up is mine.

Answer (score 0):

Let us break that $\sin$.

$$\sin(n+\frac{x}{n})=\sin(n)\cos(\frac{x}{n})+\cos(n)\sin(\frac{x}{n}).$$

You already know the convergence of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}\sin(\frac{x}{n})$, therefore the same happens for $\sum \frac{1}{n}\cos(n)\sin(\frac{x}{n})$, since $\cos(n)$ is bounded.

We only need to study

$$\sum \frac{1}{n}\sin(n)\cos(\frac{x}{n})$$

The convergen of this is equivalent to $\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$, because $\cos(\frac{x}{n})\rightarrow1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

For $\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ we can use summation by parts. Notice that the summation of $\sin(n)$ has bounded partial sums and the finite differences of $1/n$ give us a $1/n^2$ factor.

Comment: You wrote "The convergence of this is equivalent to $\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$, because $ \cos(\frac{x}{n})\rightarrow 1$ as $n \to \infty$". Can you base that statement?

Comment: A small detail: $\cos\frac{x}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$. And the argument of equivalence of terms implies similar convergence properties is only true for series with terms keeping a constant sign (either positive or negative) after a while.

Comment: @user64494 It should clearly be $\cos(\frac{x}{n})\rightarrow 1$. I was thinking on the next $\infty$ I had to write, when I wrote the first instead of a $1$.

Comment: @ClementC. You can apply it to the series of the absolute values, of course. *A bon entendeur demi-mot*.

Comment: But then one has to prove that $\sum\frac{\lvert\sin n\rvert}{n}$ converges; if I recall correctly, it is not trivial.